# Downgrading Fedora 20 kernel has failed dependencies

Tags: fedora, kernel, rpm

I currently have a virtual box Fedora 20 VM that's running kernel 3.19.8-100, however, I need 3.16.6-200.

I found the appropriate rpm file but but attempting to install gives Failed dependencies with kernel-modules-extra. I also tried installing with -oldpackage option but then it gives me the error that only installation and upgrading can be forced. Then I tried to downgrade the kernel-modules-extra package, with no success. All the errors also essentially say each package depends on itself?

How do I resolve these dependencies?

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# uname -r
3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -Uvh kernel-3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    kernel-uname-r = 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 is needed by (installed) kernel-modules-extra-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
    kernel-uname-r = 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 is needed by (installed) kernel-modules-extra-3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64
    kernel-uname-r = 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 is needed by (installed) kernel-modules-extra-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
    kernel-uname-r = 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 is needed by (installed) kernel-modules-extra-3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm --oldpackage kernel-3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64.rpm 
rpm: only installation and upgrading may be forced
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -Uvh kernel-modules-extra-3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    kernel-uname-r = 3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64 is needed by kernel-modules-extra-3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64
```

Comment: Have you tried booting from your 3.11 kernel (which is installed) and then installing the 3.16 kernel from there?

Comment: Good idea, but I just tried it and same result.

Comment: What depends on extra - modules? Besides kernel of course... Maybe you can remove extra modules, install new kernel, then add all extra modules?

Comment: That's what's weird, rpm -qR kernel-modules-extras.... says a packaged named "kernel-uname-r = 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64" depends on it.  Which if you substitute uname-r with 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 that means it depends on itself.  Looks like when those packages installed something didn't go right and the environmental variable "uname-r" became part of the package name instead of the value of the variable?  Is that what's going on here?

Comment: try `rpm -ivh --oldpackage kernel....rpm`

Comment: @user252265 No, that's normal — the kernel package has a `Provides: kernel-uname-r = 4.12.5-300.fc26.x86_64` (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

The kernel package has a number of *subpackages* which all need to be installed together (if they are installed). You can't do this piecemeal; you need to do it all in one transaction.

In Fedora, the kernel is a special case where you can have multiple versions of the same package installed. So, you probably want to use `-i` for install rather than `-U` for upgrade.

```
rpm -Uvh kernel-3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

may just work by itself, but you may want some of the subpackages — in F20 not such a big deal, but in more recent Fedora releases you'll need `kernel-core` and almost certainly `kernel-modules` unless you are running in a VM with no graphics. In this case, include those subpackages *all on the same RPM command line*.